# Intermittent errors while loading SSRS 2008 R2 report from client machine

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

Below are the errors which I am getting in different versions of the browser while loading SSRS report from the client machine. The reports are working fine on the server without any error.

In IE-5/7

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 12019
>
> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 12152

In Chrome/Firefox/IE10/Edge, Latest browsers, getting these errors:

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete
>   the operation due to error 00002ef3.
>
> SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An
>   unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The
>   status code returned from the server was: 0

Initially I thought this error is due to timeout, So I have followed these steps to remove or increase time out:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23508.sql-server-reporting-services-timeout-settings.aspx

But the error is still not resolved. At this point, I believe the actual problem lies in Microsoft’s Javascript. The issue seems to be the timeout that is being used by the Microsoft Ajax library **MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js** as returned by **ScriptResource.axd**.

I’ve been able to watch the errors appear client-side, but there are no errors getting logged in the server

I have tried to add System.Web.Extensions setting as well. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

The status 0 is not an HTTP status code, so it is probably a status code about the API being called - so check this API

May be current version of report server does not support your data query, so you could try to update your version of report server

Check firewalls and anti-virus to make sure report server and database server are reachable

Disable browser extensions to determine if they might be interfering

Use the web services URL to access the report - https://name_of_server/reportserver

Check request/response process under the browser's developer tools, and get some helpful information there

Comment: Rahul, in answer to your statement, "There can be two issues, either the timeout which can be caused by huge time taken by SP or your Data is very huge which your report is not able to render in UI. So if your SP is running fine then it comes to render data. Are you using any filters in your report or you are just dumping all the data directly to the report. How much data your SP is returning? Is it less or very huge?"..... I would say that the data returned by the SP is not very large, which is what makes it weird.

Comment: There are expressions used on the report, for sure, all embedded within the report, which do summations and other calculations and perform filtering to show or not show rows based on the result.